# HTML5 input type number currency validation failing

Tags: html, validation

I have a money textbox that I've set the type to number to enter values with two digit precision, and restrict entering letters or symbols so that way it is always in the 0.00 format. All textboxes in the form seem to validate fine until one textbox down about 7 values. The HTML5 validation occurs and is highlighted in red and states "You Must Enter A Valid Value" before form submission is allowed. I don't see how this value is not valid. I have tried multiple patterns. I "need" to have type=number to allow for setting the right keyboard in mobile devices. Setting type to text and the numeric keyboard does not show.

**This is the input that throws the error:**

```
input name="ctl00$MainContent$lvAccounts$ctrl6$txtAccountBalance" tabindex="21" class="MoneySelection jqNumeric ThisRow" id="ctl00_MainContent_lvAccounts_ctrl6_txtAccountBalance" type="number" step="0.01" pattern="^\d+\.\d{2}$" value="40980.66"
```

**But just above, along with other boxes they seem to pass (assuming top to bottom validation):**

```
input name="ctl00$MainContent$lvAccounts$ctrl5$txtAccountBalance" tabindex="21" class="MoneySelection jqNumeric ThisRow" id="ctl00_MainContent_lvAccounts_ctrl5_txtAccountBalance" type="number" step="0.01" pattern="^\d+\.\d{2}$" value="16374.29"
```

And here's another oddity... I set the value to 41980.66 and it validates fine. I set to 39980.66 and it fails, set to 31980.66 and it validates.

I've read about the novalidate option on the form, but does that affect/negate any RequiredFieldValidators? If the regex is incorrect, why does it work for some values and not others?

I've tried different patterns and inline vs jQuery attributes with no success. I was able to recreate on jsFiddle using IE11 as my browser
http://jsfiddle.net/8821dhfj/

Comment: I can confirm Chrome does not have this issue. When using the min and max attributes it "seems" to resolve issue, but only changes the cents values that throw the validation error. Change 41980.66 to 41980.67 and it fails http://jsfiddle.net/8821dhfj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use type = "number" in your JavaScript. It looks like it's unsupported in IE.

Or use [Number polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill).

Comment: thanks for reference, but looks to have its own issues with IE. Without input type=number, there seems to be no other way to display the number keypad in mobile devices.

Comment: What about using <input type="tel">? This will show the number keypad.